# How to send a multipart email with both plain text and HTML in Android?

Tags: android, email, android-intent, html-email, multipart

I'm trying to find out the cleanest way in Android to send a multipart email via an Intent. The email is supposed to include a plain-text part and an HTML part.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
String mailBody="Hello. I think you’d really enjoy this:"+
                "<a href='www.google.com/'> Search eEngine  </a>"+
                "from  Books"+"<br/><br/>"; 




                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
                emailIntent.setType("text/html"); 
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Search eEngine "); 
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml(mailBody));                         
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Comment: This is not a multipart email... this is just an HTML email.

Comment: I'd like to send a multipart email (with a plain-text part and an HTML part) with Android.